# What is the collective word for any semi-literate person that you can hire

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What is the word to describe any body that has a particular skill that did not go to college to learn the skill.

E.g carpenters, brick layers, DJ's, caterers, repair men, clowns etc.

The closest word I could find was **artisan**. However, the word artisan suggests that the person *creates or repairs things with their hands*.But I am looking for the word for anyone at all with a monetizable skill which is not taught in college or Universities.

A compound or word phrase would be acceptable.

Comment: "Semi-literate"? There are plenty of literate people who didn't go to university.

Comment: Tradesman (perhaps now tradesperson) is another word with partial coverage.

Comment: Welcome. I think a *high school graduate* would be an adequate description.

Comment: Your question is about manual trades, those who are semi-literate (needs definition), and those who did not go to college. People may belong to any of all these three types. This means that you are asking for one term to describe any of the seven possible combinations of type. This explains why you have not received a simple answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Tradesman* is about as close as it gets for a single-word umbrella term.

[AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tradesman)

> 1. A man who practices a manual trade.

[trade](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=trade)

> 6. An occupation, especially one requiring skilled labor; craft: *the building trades*.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradesman)

> A tradesman, skilled tradesman, or tradie refers to a worker who
> specializes in a particular occupation that requires work experience,
> on-the-job training, and often formal vocational education, but not a
> bachelor's degree.

*Skilled worker* also comes close, but doesn't have the blue-collar connotations that *tradesman* does.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skilled_worker)

> A skilled worker is any worker who has special skill, training,
> knowledge, and (usually acquired) ability in their work. A skilled
> worker may have attended a college, university or technical school.
> Or, a skilled worker may have learned their skills on the job.
> Examples of skilled labor include engineers, scientists, software
> development, paramedics, police officers, soldiers, physicians, crane
> operators, cdl truck drivers, machinist, drafters, plumbers,
> craftsmen, cooks and accountants. These workers can be either
> blue-collar or white-collar workers, with varied levels of training or
> education, even though they sometimes are called "purple collars".

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard anyone call a clown or a DJ a tradesman.